# Is there a similar command to Cisco's "dir all" on a HP Procurve switch?

Tags: hp-procurve, cli

I'm using a HP Procurve switch (e.g. pc2910 pc2510 pc5510)

Is there a command similar to Cisco's "dir all"  on a HP Procurve switch ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Comware switches (former 3Com aka H3C) seem to support `dir` but Provision ones don't.

You can check your firmware versions/files by running `show flash`.

Configuration files are displayed by `show config files`.

### EDIT

In *diagnostic mode* you can use `llShow` or `fs ll` to display the files in cflash, NV mem and RAM. View file contents by `fs cat <file>`

```
edomtset
edomtset
llshow cf
llshow nvfs
llshow ram
fs cat cfa0/boot.ini
```

(and possibly more, depending on the model)

**Beware of playing around in diagnostic mode. Heed the warning that is displayed when entering it - you can change settings that void your warranty or brick the switch permanently.**

Comment: I always appreciate to your reply.